# How to make 2 buttons change a label value in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I would like to know if there is a way to make 2 separate buttons change the value of 1 label. Example: Button 1 makes the label say "Hello"; while, the second button makes the label say "Goodbye". I can easily make a label display a value just by pressing a button. I have even created a counter so that when the button is pressed agin the text disappears.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - you probably mean Mac OS X (Cocoa) or iOS (Cocoa Touch) ?

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
-(IBAction)hello:(id)sender {
    label1.text = @"Hello.";
}

-(IBAction)goodbye:(id)sender {
    label1.text = @"Goodbye.";
}
```

Link up your buttons to these IBActions respectively and the label to the outlet and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks I found this to be a great way to do it!

Comment: @jrtc27: I thought that you don't need the `:(id)sender` when working with the iPhone SDK. I edited it in for safety. @Taylor T If my answer answered your question you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've had problems with them not being recognised by IB in the past, but that may have changed...

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your view controller's .m:

`-(IBAction)hello:(id)sender {

    label.text = @"Hello";

}`

-(IBAction)goodbye:(id)sender {
    label.text = @"Goodbye";
}

and the following to the .h:

`-(IBAction)hello:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)goodbye:(id)sender;`

Then in Interface Builder link the methods to the buttons. Of course you need your label to be connected via Interface Builder and have a reference in your code, but I am assuming you have done that based on the content of your question.

Answer (score 1):

**For Xcode 10.2 with Swift 5** 
You can also use Swift to change a Mac OS label with a button by using the assistant editor. Ensure your storyboard is on the left and the class connected to the window view is displayed on the right *(on a starter project the file name defaults to: ViewController.swift)*.

1. Connect the **label** to the NSViewController (control + dragging into code)   **just under the class statement** (Near the top) 
   and when the prompt appears.
    
          Connection = Outlet 
          Name = "**label**" or "your label name" 
          Type = Any 
    The resulting code will look like this 
         `@IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!`
2. Connect the **button** to the NSViewController (control + dragging into code) **usually anywhere after any of the canned override statements close to the bottom but just above the last curly bracket** 
   when the prompt appears.
          Connection = Action 
          Name = "**Button**" or "your button name" 
          Type = Any 
    The resulting code should appear like this 
         `@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {`
         `}`
3. Then add the following code between the two curly brackets created by the button connection.
    `@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
       self.label.stringValue = "New Label"
   }`
4. Run your project

LOL, I was originally having a senior moment and was searching how to change a button label when I ran across this entry and remembered how to do it. 

If you are interested in changing a button label too, it's basically the same process 
 Connect the button to the code under the class statement and make a Outlet connection just like step 1. Then, at the point in the code where you want the button label to change, add the following line of code.

```
self.button.title = "New Button Label"
```

Hopes this helps anyone who needs it.